# How to clear the IE DNS cache using javascript or the other?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dns

I want to clear InternetExplorer DNS cache usnig javascript or the other. not local DNS cache.

I know that IE process is caching DNS in own cache.

Is there any javascript code to clear IE's DNS cache?

Comment: Why would you think that IE would let you do that?

Comment: @Arafangion    Is it impossible to clear IE DNS cache?

Comment: Very few things are impossible, however, I would be astonished if IE gave a clear, simple way to do that. Actually, I would be pleasantly surprised if IE even had a DNS cache of its own, it would likely be using the underlying OS's DNS Cache.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but IE most definitely has a browser cache independent of the OS cache. The TTL is a default 30 minutes, and to be honest it's a big problem for things such as DNS based GSLB.

Answer (score 0):

Some background on browser cache and how hard it is to delete things from it:

http://dyn.com/web-browser-dns-caching-bad-thing/